# Generating executable from python script not working

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, runtime.exec, python-3.7

I'm working on generating .exe file of a python script, using pyinstaller.

I have generated the build files. The generated executable works perfectly on my local PC, but on other PC's its not working.

How can make it run on every other system.

My code contains paths of input files which are specific to my PC.
Can someone please enlighten me on this issue?

Comment: How do you know your .exe file won't work on other PCs? Show us details such as stacktrace or error report.

Comment: i copy pasted those generated build files in another PC and tried executing.It is not throwing any error instead the console window just blinks once.

Comment: Insert `input()` at the end of code of your main thread, it will halt your thread and prevent the console window blinking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Please note that i removed that link to an image of code. Code is text, and the relevant parts should be included as well formatted/indented code with your question.